# How can I change extended file properties using vba

Tags: windows, vba, vb6

Using [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787870%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I was able to write a program in vba that reads extended file properties.  Now, I'd like to make a program that can edit extended file properties - specifically property 22, the "subject" of a file.  So, given a file path, how could you edit the subject associated with that file?

Answer (score 3):

It can't be done using the method you are using now. You can install and use the Microsoft ActiveX [dsofile.dll](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8422) to both get and set extended properties using VBScript.

```
Set objFile = CreateObject("DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties")
objFile.Open("C:\My Path\MyFile.doc")
objFile.SummaryProperties.Subject = "My Subject"
objFile.Save
set objFile = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really more of a comment to jac above.  The .dll file referenced won't work on 64 bit machines, and I feel most machines today are 64 bit.  Click [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1118708/Bit-Application-Cannot-Use-DSOfile) for an open source 64 bit equivalent to the referenced dsofile.dll.

Answer (score -2):

' Make the file Read-Only

```
SetAttr "c:\temp\Sample.txt", vbReadOnly
```

' Make the file Hidden

```
SetAttr "c:\temp\Sample.txt", vbHidden
```

' Please note that if you change one attribute, the existing attribute is overwritten. For making a file as both readonly and hidden use both attributes in the function

```
SetAttr "c:\temp\Sample.txt", vbHidden + vbReadOnly
```

' Remove all atributes - convert a read-only file to read-write file, unhide the file etc

```
SetAttr "c:\temp\Sample.txt", vbNormal
```

Comment: Why is my answer downvoted? Can anyone please comment? So that I can fix or improve the answer

Comment: Way delayed, but you are talking about attributes. OP is talking about extended file properties... (On Windows: right click on a file in the File Explorer, select properties, and switch to the details tab)