# Set extended attributes of image files using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build an Excel-VBA based tool where I need to capture and edit the file attributes of image (.jpg) files stored on my hard-disk, including some extended attributes  (specifically the comment attribute).

I was able to get the code to loop through the files and capture the extended attributes like Author, Keywords, Comments etc and other properties which are visible when right clicking on the file.

I am now trying to write/edit these attributes but I am unable to find any way of doing so. It would be great if you could help with the exact code snippets for VBA.

The Code that I have used to read these attributes is below (From Alex K)

[Using VBA to get extended file attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651890)

```
Dim sFile As Variant
Dim oShell: Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim oDir:   Set oDir = oShell.Namespace("c:\foo")

For Each sFile In oDir.Items
 Debug.Print oDir.GetDetailsOf(sFile, 24) '24 - index corresponding to comments  
Next
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989882/how-can-i-change-extended-file-properties-using-vba

Answer (score 0):

```
' a bit of a play with classes works OK

'Harry S

'you need a work sheet with a command button
'and some properties listed on a row
'
' a standard module
'
' three class modules named  node , shelBtree, shelprop

' in the worksheet module
'
Option Explicit: Option Compare Text
'problem
' shell does not have nice CallByName  VBGet of VBLet as in
'            Thisp = CallByName(DSO.SummaryProperties, Ars(Dp + 1), VbGet)
'           CallByName DSO.SummaryProperties, ass(2), VbLet, Thisp & ";" & Ars(Dp + 2)
'
' however  it will replace the datemodified
' about the  only let or write property that I can work in namespace in VBA
'
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    TreeGrown = False  '
    ' store names and index in binary tree for fast searching
    ' use a collection or a dictionary  but tree is fast
    'and can also  be used as  unique value sort
    GrowShellTree
    '
    ' demo listing comment out
    pShelT.EnumThem
    '
    ShelOut "p:\testbad", Range("f6:AJ6")
    ' folder for files, range where you have a row of the properties that you want listed
    'like .. Name     Size  Rating   tags  Authors  Title Subject Folder name Folder path Folder   Participants   Path
    ' should list down columns  F  .. AJ  whatever properties for the files in the folder p:\testbad


End Sub

' in a standard module

Public pShelT As ShelBTree, TreeGrown As Boolean, WSP As ShelProp

Sub GrowShellTree()
    If Not TreeGrown Then
        Dim ObjShell, ObjFolder, li%, ws$
        Set pShelT = Nothing
        Set pShelT = New ShelBTree
        Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        Set ObjFolder = ObjShell.Namespace("C:\")  ' any folder will do

        For li = 0 To 290    ' about 285
            ws$ = ObjFolder.GetDetailsOf(ObjFolder.Items, li)
            If ws <> "" Then
                Set WSP = New ShelProp
                WSP.id = li
                WSP.Name = ws
                pShelT.Insert WSP
            End If
            Cells(li + 3, 3) = li
            Cells(li + 3, 4) = ws
        Next li
        TreeGrown = True
    End If
End Sub
Sub ShelOut(FoldN, RaP As Range)
    ' FoldN  works OK but FoldN$ is not a variant
    Dim ObjShell, ObjFolder, li%, IDx%, ws$, Fname, ro%
    GrowShellTree
    Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set ObjFolder = ObjShell.Namespace(FoldN)
    For Each Fname In ObjFolder.Items
        ro = ro + 1
        For li = 1 To RaP.Columns.Count
            IDx = pShelT.FindId(RaP(1, li))
            If IDx >= 0 And IDx < 290 Then
                RaP(ro + 2, li) = ObjFolder.GetDetailsOf(Fname, IDx)
            End If
        Next li
    Next Fname
    ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub

'

'in ShelBtree class module
'
Option Explicit: Option Compare Text
'
' a poor programmers fast dictionary
'
Private wShelProp As ShelProp, Fname$, Wid%
Private Parent As Node, NewNode As Node, Outi%
'Private m_List As ListBox
Public Sub Insert(x As ShelProp)
    Set NewNode = New Node  ' makes Left & Right nothing
    Set NewNode.fb = x
    Set wShelProp = x
    If Parent Is Nothing Then
        Set Parent = NewNode
    Else
        PutTheNode Parent
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PutTheNode(AtNode As Node)
    If wShelProp.Name > AtNode.fb.Name Then
        If Not (AtNode.Right Is Nothing) Then
            PutTheNode AtNode.Right
        Else
            Set AtNode.Right = NewNode
        End If
    End If
    ' use else if you want to add if =
    If wShelProp.Name < AtNode.fb.Name Then
        If Not (AtNode.Left Is Nothing) Then
            PutTheNode AtNode.Left
        Else
            Set AtNode.Left = NewNode
        End If
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub Findat(AtNode As Node)
    If AtNode.fb.Name = Fname Then
        Wid = AtNode.fb.id
    Else
        If AtNode.fb.Name < Fname Then
            If Not (AtNode.Right Is Nothing) Then
                Findat AtNode.Right
            Else
                Wid = -2
            End If
        End If
        If AtNode.fb.Name > Fname Then
            If Not (AtNode.Left Is Nothing) Then
                Findat AtNode.Left
            Else
                Wid = -3
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Function FindId%(Nam$)
    Fname = Nam: Wid = 0
    If Fname = "Name" Then
        FindId = 0
    Else
        If Not Parent Is Nothing Then
            Findat Parent
            FindId = Wid
        Else
            FindId = -1    ' as no tree
        End If
    End If
End Function

Public Sub EnumThem()
    Outi = 0
    If Not Parent Is Nothing Then
        Outi = 2
        RecEnum Parent
    Else
        MsgBox "Parent is nothing"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RecEnum(AtNode As Node)
    If Not (AtNode.Left Is Nothing) Then RecEnum AtNode.Left
    Outi = Outi + 1
    '
    ' two lines only for demo
    Cells(Outi, 1) = AtNode.fb.Name
    Cells(Outi, 2) = AtNode.fb.id
    '
    If Not (AtNode.Right Is Nothing) Then RecEnum AtNode.Right
End Sub
Public Sub DeleteAll()
    If Not Parent Is Nothing Then RecursiveDelete Parent
End Sub
'While deleting, first delete left then right then head
Private Sub RecursiveDelete(AtNode As Node)
    If Not (AtNode.Left Is Nothing) Then RecursiveDelete AtNode.Left
    If Not (AtNode.Right Is Nothing) Then RecursiveDelete AtNode.Right
    Set AtNode = Nothing
End Sub


'
'
'in   Node  class module
' not a big class but it does some very good work
'
Option Explicit
Public fb As ShelProp, Left As Node, Right As Node


'
' in ShelProp class module
'
Option Explicit: Option Compare Text

Private PName$, Pid%

Public Property Get id%()
    id = Pid
End Property
Public Property Let id(v%)
    Pid = v
End Property

Public Property Let Name(v$)
    PName = v
End Property

Public Property Get Name$()
    Name = PName
End Property
```